# Footer se muestra mal en algunas páginas

Tags: css, angular, diseño

Tengo la siguiente duda:
pasa que tengo un `footer` que en una pagina se ve como se muestra en las imágenes.
pero es solo en esta pagina, en otras con menor contenido se ve perfectamente

[image: Pagina con problemas]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta pagina se ve como debería verse en todas al final:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo del css es:

```
    .footer{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e0e2e4;
  bottom: 0%;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;


}
```

Cabe aclarar que el footer esta hecho en Angular como componente.

```
<div class="footer">

  <div class="social-networking" *ngFor="let icon of icon">
    <a [href]="icon.url"><img class="icon-social text-center" [src]="icon.assets" [alt]="icon.nombre"></a>
  </div>


  <div class="copy">
    <p>&copy; CAT APP. Todos los derechos reservados</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

En resumen: el footer no se ve hasta el final de la pagina, en la pagina que muestro en las 2 primeras imagenes se ve al final cuando carga la imagen, pero al hacer scroll se queda en esa posicion, y no al final de la pagina sin importar el contenido(como deberia)

Comment: Fabian, puede explicar cual es exactamente su problema? Las imágenes que comparte se prestan a muchas interpretaciones. Adicionalmente establezca la propiedad bottom en 0, no en 0%.

Comment: Es que en esa pagina, donde muestro las 2 primeras, cuando carga, el footer aparece abajo, y al hacer scroll se queda ahi, deberia estar en todas las paginas al final sin importar la cantidad de contenido que haya en cada una

Comment: Coincido con Joel Muñoz Moran. Con `bottom: 0;` debería quedarte bien.

Comment: con bottom: 0; y bottom:0%; me da el mismo resultado :(

Comment: Pregunta rápida: ¿el footer está dentro de otro contenedor?